# Fetchall() not fetching sql script column names to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I running a python script to extract snowflake sql results to dataframe.

The below is the code

```
Ctx = snowflake.connector(
  User='users'
  Role = 'user role') 

Query " Select product_id from 
product"
Resultset = 
ctx.cursor().execute(query)
Df = 
pd.DataFrame(Resultset.fetchall())
```

The print (df) is giving output as

```
  0
O p101
1 p102
```

The column name product_id is not getting fetched into df please assist

Comment: To which column then the values "p101, p102" belong to if not product_id?

Comment: Those belong to product_id only but the df is not containing column name product_id but has 0 instead. I want the df too look have product_id column name instead of 0

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the column names in the dataframe you need to use Pandas with Snowflake Python connector as documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html#using-pandas-dataframes-with-the-python-connector).
I am referring mainly to method **fetch_pandas_all()**

Here is an example that shows a dataframe that retrieves a resultset including the column names:

```
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=USER,
    password=PASSWORD,
    #authenticator='externalbrowser',
    account=ACCOUNT,
    database=DATABASE,
    role=ROLE,
    warehouse=WAREHOUSE,
    )

query = """
SELECT * FROM CITIBIKE_TRIPS LIMIT 5
"""

with ctx.cursor() as cur:
    df = cur.execute(query).fetch_pandas_all()
    print(df)

ctx.close()
```

Running it:

```
$ python pandas_test.py
            RIDE_ID RIDEABLE_TYPE          STARTED_AT            ENDED_AT       START_STATION_NAME  START_STATION_ID            END_STATION_NAME  END_STATION_ID  START_LAT  START_LNG    END_LAT    END_LNG MEMBER_CASUAL
0  7CD51C40CEEF4B0E   docked_bike 2021-04-16 07:58:58 2021-04-16 08:04:13   Dean St & Franklin Ave              4107  Bergen St & Vanderbilt Ave            4157  40.677592 -73.955637  40.679439 -73.968044        member
1  7973061875306E7C   docked_bike 2021-04-14 20:13:55 2021-04-14 20:22:15  Grand St & Elizabeth St              5382       Market St & Cherry St            5198  40.718822 -73.995960  40.710762 -73.994004        member
2  4BC4F47C2D102040   docked_bike 2021-04-20 17:14:47 2021-04-20 17:25:50  E 53 St & Lexington Ave              6617          E 81 St & York Ave            7084  40.758280 -73.970694  40.772838 -73.949892        member
3  0A4AAB9EC80E743F   docked_bike 2021-04-18 14:16:02 2021-04-18 14:23:59  Grand St & Elizabeth St              5382       Market St & Cherry St            5198  40.718822 -73.995960  40.710762 -73.994004        member
4  55EB820C035A8836   docked_bike 2021-04-11 00:02:04 2021-04-11 00:05:31   Dean St & Franklin Ave              4107  Bergen St & Vanderbilt Ave            4157  40.677592 -73.955637  40.679439 -73.968044        member
```

Comment: Tried running but iam getting warning pyarrow using incompatible version 8.0,any idea

Comment: You have a higher version of **pyarrow** than the one supported by Snowflake. You can remove it and run again **pip install "snowflake-connector-python[pandas]"** and you should get the one supported by Snowflake. I have pyarrow 6.0.1.